# Запуск нового Activity из Adapter

Tags: android, activity, adapter

Мне надо запустить `Activity` из `Adapter`. В моем коде подсвечивает красным строку с кодом `startActivity(intent)`.

**Код адаптера(сжатый):**

```
public class MultiTypeTaskAdapter extends MultiTypeExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MultiTypeTaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder,
        MultiTypeTaskAdapter.SubtaskViewHolder> {

       class TaskViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {

            private int viewType;
            private ImageButton imageButton;

            public TaskViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
                super(itemView);
                this.viewType = viewType;
            }

            public void bind(final Task task, int viewType, final int parent) {
                imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        switch (parent){
                            case PARENT_HOME:
                                showPopup(v, PARENT_HOME);
                                break;
                            case PARENT_COMPLETED:
                                deleteTask(v, PARENT_COMPLETED);
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    public void showPopup(final View v, final int parent) {
                        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), imageButton);
                        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_for_tasks, popup.getMenu());

                        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                                    case R.id.edit:
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.delete:
                                        deleteTask(v, parent);
                                        break;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        popup.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindGroupViewHolder(com.example.arraylist.MultiTypeTaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
            int viewType = getGroupViewType(flatPosition, group);
            final Task task = (Task) group;
            holder.bind(task, viewType, parent);
        }
}
```

Comment: нужно через контекст переход делать, передавайте в адаптер контекст и тогда получится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[startActivity(Intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) является методом класса `Context`, `Activity` наследует `Context` и этот метод внутри нее вызвать можно, в отличие от адаптера, который знать не знает про `startActivity`

Как верно заметил @Andrew, можно передать в конструктор адаптера `Context` и у него вызвать метод. Можно в конструктор передать слушатель и дергать его, а в активити уже вызывать `startActivity`

Comment: Я бы ещё упомянул интерфейс между активностью/адаптером где лежит RV и самим виджетов, тогда можно не передавать в конструктор контекст а просто из активности делать переход ;)